# split a QuerySet in sublists/subsets

Tags: python, django

I am running a QuerySet that returns a list resembling this:

```
{'name': 'A', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.684}
{'name': 'A', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.643}
{'name': 'A', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 301.835}
...
{'name': 'B', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.684}
{'name': 'B', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.643}
{'name': 'B', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 301.835}
...
{'name': 'C', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.684}
{'name': 'C', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.643}
{'name': 'C', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 301.835}
```

Generated this way:

```
Entries.objects
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date'))    
    .values('name', 'month')               
    .annotate(avg=Avg('value'))             
    .order_by('name')
```

So basically I have 12 entries per `name`, one per month. I was wondering if it was possible, **via query**, returning:

```
[
    [
          {'name': 'A', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.684}
          {'name': 'A', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.643}
          {'name': 'A', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 301.835}
    ],
    [
          {'name': 'B', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.684}
          {'name': 'B', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 316.643}
          {'name': 'B', 'month': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'avg': 301.835}
    ],
]
```

or if the only way is to create another object after the query has been run.

Answer (score 1):

Via a query, not really.  It's just a fundamental limitation of relational databases that queries produce data in flat table structures, not nested data.

Some database engines can be made to output XML or json with a nested structure, but that's usually through the use of subqueries, and is an advanced technique that isn't remotely accessible to the ORM.  It'd also be more work than iterating in Python.